# C++ Creating a thread with non static member function

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm trying to create a new thread in c++ with a non static member function of a class. However this seems to be crashing consistently on a mac and I can't figure out why. Here's a minimal example:

```
class A {
public:
    void hello() {
        cout << "hello" << endl;
    }

    A() {
        cout << "As constructor" << endl;
        // thread(&hello, this);
    }

    void start() {
        thread(&A::hello, this);
    }
};

int main(){
    A test;
    test.start();

}
```

I'm compiling on a mac with this:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -pthread -o hello thread.cpp
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Which C++ textbook are you using to learn how to correctly use threads in C++ program? Your textbook should explain the proper process for joining an execution thread, in order to avoid this kind of a crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is two-fold:

- `main()` does not wait for the thread to complete before destroying the `test` object, which CAN cause a crash.
- `start()` is not storing the `std::thread` object anywhere, so it gets destroyed immediately, which WILL cause a crash because the thread is still joinable and the `std::thread` destructor calls `std::terminate()` to kill the calling process if the thread is joinable.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
class A {
private:
    std::thread thrd;

public:
    void hello() {
        cout << "hello" << endl;
    }

    A() {
        cout << "As constructor" << endl;
    }

    ~A() {
        cout << "As destructor" << endl;
        wait();
    }

    void start() {
        thrd = thread(&A::hello, this);
    }

    void wait() {
        if (thrd.joinable())
            thrd.join();
    }
};

int main(){
    A test;
    test.start();
    // do something else while the thread is running...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should call [`std::thread::join`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) to block the current thread until the thread created finishing execution. Otherwise the current thread might finish and cause the object `test` to be destroyed in advance.

e.g.

```
void start() {
    thread t(&A::hello, this);
    t.join();
}
```

Comment: Note that using a local `thread` object and `join()` inside of `start()` like this effectively makes `start()` synchronous, defeating the purpose of using a thread at all.  This solution basically has the same effect as doing `void start() { hello(); }` just with more overhead on the OS.